# Pass default arguments with click module in Python

Tags: python

I'm using [click](https://palletsprojects.com/p/click/) to execute commands from command line. I'm trying to call a method with defaults values because the command can be used by an administrator or an user. My simplified code:

**user.py**:

```
import click


from .commands.run import run


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


cli.add_command(run)
#cli.add_command('run param1 param2'.split())) # I would like to do this, or similar
# More user commands
```

**admin.py:**

```
import click


from .user.commands.run import run


@click.group()
def adm():
    pass


adm.add_command(run) # This is OK
# More user and admin commands
```

**run.py**

```
import click
import docker


@click.command()
@click.argument('param1')
@click.argument('param2')
@click.argument('param3')
def run(param1, param2, param3):

    # Some logic with params
```

I'm not sure if this is possible with this library

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the sys module, the code might be simpler

About sys: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Comment: How would you suggest using `sys` here?  The only overlap I see between `sys` and `click` is that you can manually parse `sys.argv`, but I would argue that that wouldn't simplify the code.